# An Olympiad irreducibility problem

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

Let $p$ be an irreducible polynomial in $\Bbb Q[x]$ and degree larger than $1$. Prove that if $p$ has two roots $r$ and $s$ whose product is $1$ then the degree of $p$ is even.

My approach: Let $Q(x)=P(1/x)P(0)x^d$. Note they have two roots in common. If they are the same polynomial, this is trivial, as otherwise the irreduciblility is contradicted. Then there are two minimal polynomials with roots $r$ and $1/r$, but then I’m stuck. Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Yours is a good approach. Now, hint: Show that $P = Q$ (maybe up to scalar?). What does this mean about "opposite" coefficients of $P$ ? Now, can you factor something out from $x^u + x^{d-u}$ ?

Comment: If I show $P=Q$, I'm done.

Comment: Show that both $P$ and $Q$ are minimal polynomials of $r$.

Comment: Actually, I solved the problem right after it is posted.

Comment: I have a solution on aops. I'm KaiDaMagical336